# how to select based on comma separated values in column

Tags: mysql, csv, select, tags

In my table, one of the column has comma separated values. I would like to select the entry based on one or two values if found in that column like

```
select * from table where tags contains ('ec2' or 'associate')
```

or contains multiple values

```
select * from table where tags contains 's3' and 'rds'
```

What is the right query?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the in-built [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
find_in_set('s3',tags) > 0 and find_in_set('rds',tags) > 0
```

Comment: What should the type of column? Should I change it to SET?
Also it doesn't seem to be searching second/third/.. values after comma?

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy you will need to use `REPLACE(tags, ' ', '')` to remove all the whitespace from your `tags` value for `FIND_IN_SET` to work properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `like` operator:

```
select * from table 
where 
  concat(',', tags, ',') like '%,s3,%' 
  and
  concat(',', tags, ',') like '%,rds,%'
```

if in `tags` after each `,` there is a space then:

```
select * from table 
where 
  concat(', ', tags, ',') like '%, s3,%' 
  and
  concat(', ', tags, ',') like '%, rds,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using mysql regular expression function [REGEXP_LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) :

```
REGEXP_LIKE(tags, '(^|,)\s*ec2\s*($|,)' )
AND REGEXP_LIKE(tags, '(^|,)\s*associate\s*($|,)' )
```

As it does need not modify the compared value, it might perform better than the solution using `LIKE`.

Regex explanation :

- `(^|,)` : beginning of the string OR a comma
- `\s*` : 0 or more consecutive spaces
- `ec2` : string to search for
- `\s*` : 0 or more consecutive spaces
- `($|,)` : end of the string OR a comm

If you want an `OR` filter instead of `AND`, it can be expressed in a single function call, like :

```
REGEXP_LIKE(tags, '(^|,)\s*((ec2)|(associate))\s*($|,)' )
```

Comment: OPs data has spaces after the comma, you need to allow for that in your regex.